# decimal.Decimal as default type in stead of float

Tags: python, python-3.x, overriding

Is it possible to change the "default" datatypes in python? Such that when I declare a variable with a value `0.2`, it will be a `decimal.Decimal` in stead of a `float`?
The only thing I could think of was this

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> float = Decimal
>>> float(".2")+float(".1")
Decimal('0.3')
```

Which is kinda the behaviour I wanted, but not quite:

```
>>> .2+.1
0.30000000000000004
```

I expected similar results as with `float(".2")+float(".1")`, but I guess `x=.1` is handled differently than `x=float(".1")`.

Is there any way to achieve the first behaviour without excplicitly calling `float()`?

Comment: No; you cannot change the behavior of a literal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can literals in Python be overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083160/can-literals-in-python-be-overridden)